# Command to remove all files except some latest one which work for both solaris and linux

Tags: linux, shell, solaris

I am trying one command which remove all files from a location except the latest one. I have working command for linux but its not working on solaris machine.

The below command will remove all files except last 10.

```
ls -l /*.tps | head -n -10 | rm -rf
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ls -t {pattern} | tail -n +2 | xargs rm
```

In slow-mo:

- list all files sorted by time, newest first
- print starting with 2nd (so skip first)
- pass names to `rm`

Comment: thanks @xenoid but it wont work. I have working command but its not working on solaris box. Solaris doen't take  2 argument for head/tail command.  (tail -n +2)

Comment: @Ankit Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314321/whats-the-solaris-equivalent-to-the-bsds-tail-n100) help?

Answer (score 0):

Following the Oracle man pages and assuming you mean with 'the latest' 'the newest' files, I am suggesting the following approach:

`ls -1tr | tail -n +11 | xargs rm` for linux and

`ls -1tr | /usr/xpg4/bin/tail -n +11 | xargs rm` for [oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/816-5165/tail-1.html)

Answer (score 0):

To remove all files from a location except the latest one, you may use this cross-platform command:

```
ls -1t /location | sed -n '2,$p' | xargs rm
```

Sed program `2,$p` prints every line since 2 to the end of input.